# Use JQuery to select a dynamic ID based on URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've looked around quite a bit (a couple of hours now) at the various answers provided for this type of scenario, but I'm not a programmer, so I get stuck on what are probably very simple matters. Here's the situation: I have a jquery dynamic menu (based on a jquery [lava lamp menu](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-lava-lamp-style-navigation-menu/)) that positions a navigation image depending on the ID of an item on the page. This ID matches the last part of the URL, with the words "primary-menu-" inserted before the URL. So, I have:

```
example.com/blog
example.com/about
```

The ID for the list-item navigation element for the above URLs is:

```
id="primary-menu-blog"
id="primary-menu-about"
```

The (snipped) Jquery code I have to select these dynamic items (which I have copied from various answers to similar questions) is:

```
var url = '/';
var id = parseInt(url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 1]);
var nav = $(this),
currentPageItem = $("#primary-menu-" + id, nav),
```

I have managed to get this dynamic menu working on a [sample page](http://www.testing.rosslaird.com/GGS.html) that does not have the dynamically-changing IDs. But naturally, it doesn't work with the new code because I don't know enough about this. But I think I am on the right track. Suggestions most welcome.

Edit: after trying to implement suggestions in this thread, with no success, I figure I must be missing something simple. So, for the sake of clarity, here is full the script (it's not that long...):

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.spasticNav = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      overlap : 0,
      speed : 500,
      reset : 1500,
      color : 'none',
      easing : 'easeOutExpo'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      # Added by Me, for testing on localhost;
      var url = 'localhost:8000/';
      var id = url.split('/').pop();
      # End Added by Me.
        var nav = $(this),
      currentPageItem = $("#primary-menu-" + id, nav),
      blob,
      reset;
      $('<li id="blob"></li>').css({
        width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
        height : currentPageItem.outerHeight() + options.overlap,
        left : currentPageItem.position().left,
        top : currentPageItem.position().top - options.overlap / 2,
        backgroundColor : options.color
      }).appendTo(this);
      blob = $('#blob', nav);
      $('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function() {
        // mouse over
        clearTimeout(reset);
        blob.animate(
          {
          left : $(this).position().left,
          width : $(this).width()
        },
        {
          duration : options.speed,
          easing : options.easing,
          queue : false
        }
        );
      }, function() {
        // mouse out    
        reset = setTimeout(function() {
          blob.animate({
            width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
            left : currentPageItem.position().left
          }, options.speed)
        }, options.reset);

      });
    }); // end each
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: How about you tell us what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to parse the URL. You could just use an attribute selector to select any element whose ID starts with `primary-menu-`:

```
var currentPageItem = $(this).find('[id^="primary-menu-"]');
```

---

If you absolutely must use the URL, use this:

```
var id = window.location.href.split('#')[0].split('?')[0].split('/').pop(),
    currentPageItem = $(this).find('#primary-menu-' + url);
```

Comment: which still will do nothing for dynamially added content. Until he reveals what his plan for that selector is we can't start the inevitable "omg use .live()" "omg .live() is depracated" discussion ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What I am trying to do is select the (dynamic) ID. That's it. The jquery code works perfectly when I use a static ID such as "selected": it slides an image across the list of nav links and returns to settle on "selected." The only thing I am changing is what it selects.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code like this.

```
var url = 'example.com/blog';
var id = url.split('/').pop();
var nav = $(this),
currentPageItem = $("#primary-menu-" + id, nav);
```

Comment: Use `url.split('/').pop()` instead of `url.split('/').reverse()[0]`.

Comment: @JosephSilber - Thanks totally forgot that :P